# Connecting worker role with EF 6 to Azure sql database

Tags: azure, entity-framework-6, azure-worker-roles

I'm trying to set up a worker role to read and act based on data from Azure sql database. 
I set the connection string like this:

```
public DBEntities(string connectionString) : base(connectionString) {}
```

Whenever I try to run the worker role localy I get the following error when querying the entities:

System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.UnintentionalCodeFirstException: 'The context is being used in Code First mode with code that was generated from an EDMX file for either Database First or Model First development.

To query the entities:

```
using (ctx = new CODDBEntities(_connectionString))
{
   var result =  ctx.entity.ToList().FindAll();
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you're specifying the Database Initialization Strategies.

Try the Following:

```
public CODDBEntities()
{
    Database.SetInitializer<CODDBEntities>(null);//Disable initializer
}
```

more info in here: http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/database-initialization-strategy-in-code-first.aspx

Comment: Thanks Thiago but iI need the opposite. I'm using a database first approach. What I don't understand is why when using unit test to run the code above it works and when using the worker role, the excecution goes to the OnModelCreating function.

Answer (score 0):

Finnaly I got it. Using [this](https://blog.oneunicorn.com/2012/02/26/dont-use-code-first-by-mistake/) article I understood that I was using the wrong connection string type. I needed to use the one starting like - metadata=res://*/..." while I just coiped the default connection string from the Azure portal.